# Oracle-sqlplus

Tags: sqlplus

I am using **set colsep'|'** in sqlplus.However,It appends the pipe(|) column-sperator in between two columns only not at the begining and the end of the column.Example-It give output like this-
emp_name|emp_department|emp_salary

I want the out put like this(Append "|") in the begning and end also:
|emp_name|emp_department|emp_salary| 
 How can i acchieve this in oracle using sqlplus,Pls. help me out...ur early response can ease my nerve!!!

Comment: It may be out of purpose, but why do you need such column seprator at the beginning and at the end ?

Comment: We are doing the migration Project(migrating from sybase to Oracle) and the out in sybase is likr that and I want the same in Oracle....That's why!!!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think sqlplus let you do that. As you know, separators columns are here for, well.. separe two columns.
You can always do your request like that :

```
select '|' || col1, col2, col3, col4 || '|'
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   NULL,               -- select your left most |
   your_first_column,
   another_column_1,
   another_column_2,
   your_last_column,
   NULL                -- select right mose |
 from
   your_table;
```